# How I can Sort this Draggable List in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Link for Practice
https://demoqa.com/sortable

I tried with this code

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"demo-tabpane-list\"]/div/div"));
for(int i=5;i>=0;i--) {


action.dragAndDrop(elements.get(0), elements.get(i)).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do there? I see the elements are already appearing sorted there

Comment: Actually, I am trying to Sort elements in reverse order. If I will manually drag the element from one position to another position then also Order should not need to change. Atlast I want to sort the elements in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//* [@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div"));
    
for(int i =1;i<list.size();i++) {
        
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div["+ i +"]"));
        
        WebElement destination6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[6]"));
        WebElement destination5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[5]"));
        WebElement destination4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[4]"));
        WebElement destination3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[3]"));
        WebElement destination2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[2]"));
        WebElement destination1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[1]"));
        
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        
        if(element!=null) {
        action.dragAndDrop(element, destination6).perform();
        action.dragAndDrop(element, destination5).perform();
        action.dragAndDrop(element, destination4).perform();
        action.dragAndDrop(element, destination3).perform();
        action.dragAndDrop(element, destination2).perform();
        action.dragAndDrop(element, destination1).perform();
        break;
        }
    }

Please enhance it as per your need.
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to Sort elements in reverse order. If I will manually drag the element from one position to another position then also Order should not need to change. Atlast I want to sort the elements in reverse order. Can you please help me?

Comment: Thank you for response, Can you help me with adject solution?

Comment: can you check with the above answer

Comment: Thank you for help, but I am adding Debug Point at line,  where Action Object is defined. After that I drag one with Four and  Three with Two. So Atlast it's fail.

Comment: Are you dragging that element manually? coz the code just sorts the elements in descending order.

Comment: Yes, After manually drag also order should need to same.

Comment: Can you please help me how can I perform this task?

Comment: What is the point of automating those if you are debugging it and changing sequence of it manually?

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the elements, you need to get each element and drag it to a destination.

The solution below basically drags and drops each sortable element above the table (although this uses C#, I think logic can be used in Java).
In this case I set the destination to the List Tab to ensure the the element is above the list.
Reason: When I tried to set it to the 1st row, it goes to the second row.

The logic is as follows

- Drag/drop element 2 above 1
- Drag/drop element 3 above 2
- Drag/drop element 4 above 3
- Drag/drop element 5 above 4
- Drag/drop element 6 above 5

  ```
    // Function to sort the elements
    public void SortElements()
    {
        var action = new Actions(webDriver);
        action.DragAndDrop(sortablePage.GetSortableElementByIndex(2), sortablePage.GetListTab()).Perform();
        action.DragAndDrop(sortablePage.GetSortableElementByIndex(3), sortablePage.GetListTab()).Perform();
        action.DragAndDrop(sortablePage.GetSortableElementByIndex(4), sortablePage.GetListTab()).Perform();
        action.DragAndDrop(sortablePage.GetSortableElementByIndex(5), sortablePage.GetListTab()).Perform();
        action.DragAndDrop(sortablePage.GetSortableElementByIndex(6), sortablePage.GetListTab()).Perform();
    }

    // Create a method to get the sortable element by index
    public IWebElement GetSortableElementByIndex(int index)
    {
        return WaitForElementByXPath(wait, $"//div[@id='demo-tabpane-list']/div/div[{index}]");
    }

    // Create a method to get the Tab above the list
    public IWebElement GetListTab()
    {
        return WaitForElementById(wait, $"demo-tab-list");
    }
  ```

If you want to check more details of the C# code, you may refer to the following:
https://github.com/lorvindc/web-ui-specflow-framework